# Dummy Objects vs. NULLs: optionality for three-way relationship

Tags: database-design

In a nutshell, I'm trying to model a relationship and can't decide whether to allow NULLs or to require values and use dummy objects (in place of NULL).

Here are the details.

I have three classes:

- **Client**: a person (or company) that wants to buy some resources.
- **Broker**: a person that sells resources.
- **Resource**: a more-or-less infinitely renewable (in the sense that several clients can purchase the same one) product.  For example, access to a proprietary data set, use of an image library, contractor/professional services.

The typical use case is that a Client goes through a Broker who provides the desired Resource.  Brokers have areas of expertise and only sell some of the available Resources, and multiple Brokers may sell the same Resource.  So my initial data model looked like this:

[image: fig 1. naive many-to-many-to-many.]
fig 1. naive many-to-many-to-many.

It's basically a many-to-many-to-many relationship.  The problem is that I can't tell which Resources have been purchased by a given Client, and vice versa.  So I came up with this:

[image: fig 2. three-way relationship.]
fig 2. three-way relationship.

Now a Client buys an Instance of a Resource from a Broker.  This is what happens most of the time, but there are some exceptions that the data model must accommodate, and that this one doesn't.

- A few Resources are available as self-service and may be purchased w/out a Broker.
- A Client can buy something from a Broker which is not a Resource (think ad-hoc consulting, or a free consultation, for example).
- This model no longer captures which Resources may be sold by a particular Broker; if a Broker is allowed to sell a Resource, but hasn't yet, there's no way to record that.

Basically, I need a way to make any one of the three classes optional in any given instance of this otherwise three-way relationship.  So I can associate a Client w/ a Resource, but no Broker; and a Broker w/ a Resource, but no Client; and so on.

I can see two different approaches:

Option 1: Change all the "1..1" cardinalities in figure 2 to "0..1" so that each class is optional in the Instance relationship.  This would allow me to handle exceptions listed above, but then I'd have to deal with nulls and implement constraints at the application layer (to prevent an Instance with only one related object, for example).

Option 2: Keep all the "1..1" cardinalities, and use dummy objects to fill in the NULL holes in the model.  For example, use a dummy Broker called "self-service" to deal with Clients purchasing Resources w/out a Broker.  This would keep my data model simple, but I suspect dealing with all the special cases around dummy objects will be worse than using NULLs and application-enforced constraints on data.

**So here's my specific question**: Is there a standard data modeling design pattern that captures the sort of three-way relationship I've described above?  And if not, what are the other pros and cons I haven't yet thought of to each of the approaches above?